# Zephyr for JIRA options

Tags: automation, jira-zephyr

Is there any option in zephyr for JIRA to mark the test as automated.
I am new to JIRA and we use Zephyr for Test case management.
I am writing test cases for the web based application wanted to keep track of manual and automated test cases seperately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible right now. Automated tests and manual test cases needs to be updated manually in Zephyr plugin.

Please read this thread to get further clarity:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-do-I-execute-automated-tests-from-JIRA-Zephyr/qaq-p/165685

I not sure of ZAPI,you try that .Its another plugin from zephyr

Answer (score 0):

You can use different wordings in the Labels field but i guess you want something more sophisticated than that.
Zephyr JIRA plugin doesn't offer a lot of capabilities, however they have a separate tool called Zephyr Enterprise that has such a capability (To Mark Manual / Automated)